# Makefile : wildcard and different dependencies

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile for building a lot of libraries that depend on each other. The way I build them is always the same.

It could be like:

```
    #Makefile

    all: commonprefix_lib1 commonprefix_lib2 commonprefix_lib3

    commonprefix_lib1 : commonprefix_lib2 commonprefix_lib3
        cd $@ && autoreconf -if && ./configure && make && sudo make install

    commonprefix_lib2 : commonprefix_lib3
        cd $@ && autoreconf -if && ./configure && make && sudo make install

    commonprefix_lib3 :
        cd $@ && autoreconf -if && ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Is this possible to use a wildcard rule so that I do not repeat the cd/configure/make stuff knowning that they all have different dependencies?

```
    #Makefile

    commonprefix_% : ???
        cd $@ && autoreconf -if && ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Comment: %-style syntax is specific to GNU make. Also, you should make it so that one can add parameters to ./configure. Perhaps what you really are looking for is AC_CONFIG_SUBDIR.

Comment: Hello Jorgensen, I would like to use GNU make for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can state the dependencies separately from the pattern rule:

```
#Makefile

all: commonprefix_lib1 commonprefix_lib2 commonprefix_lib3

commonprefix_lib1 : commonprefix_lib2 commonprefix_lib3
commonprefix_lib2 : commonprefix_lib3

commonprefix_% :
    cd $@ && autoreconf -if && ./configure && make && sudo make install
```